# How to use replacement pattern in css?

Tags: 7, views, theming

Is it possible to use tokens such as [view_node] in css ?
I want to display links only for a particular content type.

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide more details, what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming your view uses `Show: fields`.**

Add `type` as a field, check mark the hide from view box.

Click on your field, in REWRITE RESULTS, checkmark rewrite outlput of field

In there, put `<div class="all-links [type]">[field_name]</div>`

Then in CSS

```
.all-links { display: none; }
.all-links.article { display: block !important; }
```

---

Another solution, is to use [Views Conditional](http://Views%20Conditional)

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views.

Then just do a simple condition if `type` is x, then `[field_name]`

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a solution for this question, ie if those "links" are about a column which you want to show without links for "other" content types. Your solution excludes the entire row from the views results, no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Merci, answer adjusted, I originally missed read the question.

Comment: "***Adjusted***"??? Replaced entirely you mean ... by an answer which IMO should do the job ... Sorry I couldn't resist to critique your prior  version of your answer ...

Comment: If you change the row style output (display or style settings in left top) there is also a classes field that accepts tokens. Here you can apply a class for the whole row and you do not have to create div's yourself.

Comment: @Neograph734 true, but here you just want to apply the class to the link field, well.. unless the entire row is just the link, then your suggestion is a valid alternative.

Comment: True, It is a matter of habit I guess. I prefer to drop 2 classes in the dedicated fields (also using rewrite output of the field), rather than adding HTML elements :) you get .[type] .my_field_class {}